# Can anyone help in understanding AVFrame.linesize[]?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, libavcodec, stride

I tried to find what each cell of `AVFrame.linesize[]` means, but I didn't found.

As I understood `linesize[0]` is the width, `linesize[1]` is the height.

1. If I'm right what does other cells mean?
2. why after `avcodec_decode_video2(codecCtxDecode, frameDecoded, &frameFinished, &packet);` only linesize[0] has the value and other cells are always 0?

**UPDATED**

I think AVFrame.data[i] and AVFrame.linesize[i] are the data of specific color in the row and the length of the row, am I correct?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In the case of planar data, such as `YUV420`, `linesize[i]` contains stride for the `i`-th plane.

For example, for frame `640x480` `data[0]` contains pointer to `Y` component, `data[1]` and `data[2]` contains pointers to `U` and `V` planes. In this case, `linesize[0] == 640`, `linesize[1] == linesize[2] == 320` (because the `U` and `V` planes is less than `Y` plane half)

In the case of pixel data (`RGB24`), there is only one plane (`data[0]`) and `linesize[0] == width * channels` (`640 * 3` for `RGB24`)

Comment: hi, After `avcodec_decode_video2(dc, yuvFrame, &got_picture, &h264packet);` if i print `linesize`, it's not as you stated. why the linesize is such huge(a large 8 digit number) ?

Comment: this is super old but the reason it's a huge 8 bit number is because it's a pointer to an array, not an integer.

Comment: How come then, if I have a YUV420p frame with resolution 500x500, `linesize[0] == 512`?

Comment: @BenjaminCrawfordCtrl-Alt-Tut Each next line in Y plane begin 512 bytes after previous even though it contains 500 significant bytes

Comment: linesize[0] may be greater than the width. Check this one too https://stackoverflow.com/a/57666844/3871242

Comment: @pogorskiy You mentioned that ***linesize[0] == 640, linesize[1] == linesize[2] == 320*** Aren't UV planes interleaved on a single plane in case of 4:2:0, why to to mention plane 2 then ? If I am wrong could you correct me ?

Comment: Note that `width` and `linesize[0]` might not correspond (same for `width/2` and `linesize[1]` and `linesize[2]`. if ffmpeg decides to add padding, it happened to me while I was trying to encode an image of width 1200, not divisible by 32!

Answer (score 13):

Have a look at description of video frame formats:

- [YUV pixel formats](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php)
- [Video Media Types - Image Stride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa473780)

You will see that formats are split into two big groups: packed and planar, depending on whether the components are kept separately or interleaved. Strides have slightly different meaning for those, and basically they are number of bytes you need to skip to advance by a row.