# AVFrame confusion between width, height and linesize

Tags: c++, opengl, ffmpeg

I'm trying to understand AVFrame, specially the linesize property.

Here's my decoded AVFrame properties:

```
width = 640 
height= 360

linesize[0] = 640
linesize[1] = 320
linesize[2] = 320
```

It's an YUV 420 planar image (`AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ420P`)

I'm reading [this code](https://github.com/yuan631111976/qtavplayer/blob/b4394d620076cedb05fdc006daee2918baeb73d9/AVOutput.cpp) and here's the part that deals with AVFrame properties:

```
int linesize = qAbs(m_format.renderFrame->linesize[i]);
AVRational widthRational = params.yuvwidths[i];
AVRational heightRational = params.yuvheights[i];
int width = linesize * widthRational.num / widthRational.den;
int height = m_format.renderFrame->height * heightRational.num / heightRational.den;
glTexImage2D ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, params.yuvInternalformat[i],width ,height, 0, params.yuvGlFormat[i], params.dataType, NULL);
```

Where, for  YUV420P, `widthRational` and `heightRational` are `1/1` and `1/1` for `i=0`, and `1/2` and `1/2` for `i = 1,2`. And `yuvInternalformat` and `yuvGlFormat` are always `GL_RED`.

There are a few things that I can't understand in ths code:

Why he takes an absolute value in `linesize`? Can `linesize` be negative? There's nothing about negative values in the documentation. I understand why he makes the fraction multiplication in `height`, but why in `linesize`? Shouldn't `linesize` be the actual `width` of the planar image and thus require no multiplication?

So what is `linesize`, how should `width` and `height` be calculated in order to use `glTexImage2D`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Height is height in pixels, Nothing special about that.

Width is width in pixels of the displayed image.

Stride, or linesize, the the width of each row of pixels in memory. The line size must be equal to or greater than the width. For example, a 1920x1080 commonly has has a line size of 1088 to make the stride evenly divisible by 16, but the 8 right most columns of pixels are not displayed.

Chroma subsampling is a different thing. For some color formats, like yuv420p, The first plane (the black and white plane) is full resolution, But the 2 color planes, are quarter resolution, (half height and half width). In my 1920x1080 example, This make the height of the second and third plane 960, the width 540, and the stride (most likely) 544 (544 = ceil(1080/16)*16).

Other color formats like RGB, or yuv444p, will have the second and third plane the same dimensions as the first.

Comment: If the linesize must be >= the width, how did my width=640, but linesize[1]=320? What that means? And what you mean by "line size of 1920x1088"? As I understood, linesize is a number slightly greater than width. What number is it that you meant by 1920x1088?

Comment: Please reread my response. I specifically explained that by describing chroma sub sampling.

Comment: I think 1088 is just floor(1080/16)*16, so that it make the height divisible by 16. 1920 is already divisible by 16, thus doesn't need to make up some padding.

However, when I work on screen capture, some screen has a linesize = 2*W, some screen has linesize=4*W, printing out the formats after avformat_open_input are always using AV_PIX_FMT_UYVY422.
avFormatContext.streams(0).codecpar().format() = AV_PIX_FMT_UYVY422
I am not sure if it is because this error: "Selected pixel format (yuv420p) is not supported by the input device"

Comment: @szatmary "but the 8 right-most columns of pixels are not displayed"

How exactly do you tell openGL to ignore extra stride/padding? My width is 1080 and linesize is 1152. I am seeing those padding when I render with openGL. Every video frame seems to have right black edge being rendered. I am getting AVFrame and uploading the Y plane to GPU and then accessing from shader